# How to remove last utf8 char of a python string

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I have a string containing utf-8 encoded text. I need to remove the last utf-8 character.

So far I did

```
msg = msg[:-1]
```

but this only removes the last byte. It works as long as the last character is an ASCII code. It doesn't work anymore when the last character is a multibyte character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to decode your UTF-8 bytes to Unicode text:

```
without_last = msg.decode('utf8')[:-1]
```

You can always encode it again.

The alternative would be for you to search for a [UTF-8 start byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description); UTF-8 byte sequences always start with a byte with the most significant bit set to `0`, or the two most significant bits set to `1`, while continuation bytes always start with `10`:

```
# find starting byte of last codepoint
pos = len(msg) - 1
while pos > -1 and ord(msg[pos]) & 0xC0 == 0x80:
    # character at pos is a continuation byte (bit 7 set, bit 6 not)
    pos -= 1
msg = msg[:pos]
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the second sotution because the former didn't work. The second solution works very well.

Comment: @chmike The first solution works for me if you don't forget to call `without_last.encode('utf-8')` after that.